# SQL SERVER QUERY WITH PIVOT AND GROUPED INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have try the `PIVOT` approach and the `CASE WHEN` but I have not figured out how to get this result from the table I have.

This is what we need:

```
personnel_id  SATURDAY SUNDAY  MONDAY   TUESDAY   WEDNESDAY THURSDAY  FRIDAY
Juan Jose       OFF     OFF     6-2        6- 2      OFF      OFF      6-2
```

from those tables:

```
[TABLES FROM SQL SERVER][1]
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT  
    personnel_name, 
    CASE WHEN day_name = 'saturday' then entrada END AS SAT,
    CASE WHEN day_name = 'sunday' then entrada END AS SUN,
    CASE WHEN day_name = 'monday' then entrada END AS MON,
    CASE WHEN day_name = 'tuesday' then entrada END AS TUE,
    CASE WHEN day_name = 'wednesday' then entrada END AS WED,
    CASE WHEN day_name = 'thursday' then entrada END AS THUR,
    CASE WHEN day_name = 'friday' then entrada END AS FRI
FROM
   (SELECT 
        personnel_name, tbl_shifts.entrada, tbl_days.day_name
    FROM 
        tbl_personnel_weekshift 
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_personnel ON tbl_personnel_weekshift.personnel_id = tbl_personnel.personnel_id
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_shifts ON tbl_personnel_weekshift.shift_id = tbl_shifts.shift_id
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_days ON tbl_personnel_weekshift.day_id = tbl_days.day_id) AS IIIPO;
```

which returns these results:

[RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7rP5.jpg)

```
Juan Jose Moreno OFF    NULL    NULL NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
Juan Jose Moreno NULL   OFF     NULL NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
Juan Jose Moreno NULL   NULL    6-2  NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
Juan Jose Moreno NULL   NULL    NULL 6-2    NULL    NULL    NULL
Juan Jose Moreno NULL   NULL    NULL NULL   OFF     NULL    NULL
Juan Jose Moreno NULL   NULL    NULL NULL   NULL    OFF     NULL
Juan Jose Moreno NULL   NULL    NULL NULL   NULL    NULL    6-2
```

I need to find a good approach or find a way to group by in only one row and get rid of the nulls.

Thanks for your time and effort Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT personnel_name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN day_name = 'saturday' then entrada END) AS SAT,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day_name = 'sunday' then entrada END) AS SUN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day_name = 'monday' then entrada END) AS MON,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day_name = 'tuesday' then entrada END) AS TUE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day_name = 'wednesday' then entrada END) AS WED,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day_name = 'thursday' then entrada END) AS THUR,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day_name = 'friday' then entrada END) AS FRI
FROM (SELECT personnel_name, tbl_shifts.entrada, tbl_days.day_name
      FROM tbl_personnel_weekshift INNER JOIN
           tbl_personnel
           ON tbl_personnel_weekshift.personnel_id = tbl_personnel.personnel_id INNER JOIN
           tbl_shifts
           ON tbl_personnel_weekshift.shift_id = tbl_shifts.shift_id INNER JOIN
           tbl_days
           ON tbl_personnel_weekshift.day_id = tbl_days.day_id
     ) IIIPO
GROPU BY personnel_name;
```